# Series Trouble / Diverging

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does anyone mind explaining both of these questions, I’m stuck.

> 3. Determine whether the sequence converges or diverges. If it converges, find the limit it converges to. $$\left\lbrace\sqrt[n]{2^{1 + 2n}}\right\rbrace_{n = 1}^\infty$$
> 4. Find the general $n^{th}$ term of the sequence. Then determine whether the sequence converges or diverges. If it converges, find the limit it converges to. $$\left\lbrace 1, \frac42, \frac96, \frac{16}{24}, \frac{25}{120}, \cdots\right\rbrace$$

Comment: Problem 3:  Are you able to simplify the expression in braces to $2^{\text{something}}$?  If so, show us how you did it.  Problem 4:  Are you able to find/guess a formula for the $n^\text{th}$ term in the sequence?  If so, show us what you got.

Comment: for both problems, my struggle is I don’t really see what the pattern is.

Comment: Can you do the first one if the $1+$ isn't in the exponent?

Comment: is it not just the number multiplied by 2? I apologize if this seems easy, i genuinely get so confused with these.

Answer (score 0):

The second one (problem 4) seems to be $u_n = \frac{n^2}{n!}$ and as $$0 \le u_n \le \frac{n}{n-1}\frac{1}{n-2} \le \frac{4}{n}$$
for $n \ge 4$, it converges to zero.